# PHP Unit Testing - Mock static autoloaded class with Mockery

Tags: php, unit-testing, static, composer-php, mockery

I want to unit test a wrapper class for the official Segment PHP integration. Therefore I'll have to mock [the Segment class](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-php/blob/master/lib/Segment.php) with Mockery so there won't be any real API requests.

**The Problem**

The class to mock consists only of static methods. Because of this I try to mock it like this (with [alias](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/startup_methods.html)):

`$segment = Mockery::mock('alias:Segment');`

This works, but only if the class isn't autoloaded by composer. If I load it - like I have to for the rest of the app - I'll get the error

`Could not load mock Segment, class already exists.`

(That makes sense, because the docs state that an aliased class must not be loaded before.)

**The question**

How can I mock this (evil?) class, but still use it as usual in the rest of my app?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this sounds more like a design issue than a question on "how to mock it". How exactly does your class where you reference that library look like? Are you somehow injecting the dependency or are you just straight calling the library directly from your methods?

Comment: I thought about that, too, but couldn't come up with a solution. At the moment I call the methods straight like this: `Segment::track(...)`. It wouldn't make sense to inject the class, because it only got static methods, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think it would make perfect sense since that would allow you to pass the mocked version of it from your test. It may seem unnecessary in production since it requires additional setup for your class, but I think that's the common approach to make a class testable. And if you have the ability to use a Dependency Injection Container (like [PHP-DI](https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI)), that would be a non-issue.

Comment: Yeah, an additional wrapper would also be a good solution, but then you still would have to test that wrapper and bump into the same issue. Also, your class already *is* a wrapper, so I think that would be just wrapper-ception :) Think of it that way: All you want to test is that a specific method on some object is called. The best way to do this is to be in control of what that object is, and to allow for that, you just pass it in from the outside instead of autoloading it within your class. In production you then pass the real class, and in your test case you pass a mock.

Comment: Mh, I see. But that means that I would inject an instance of the Segment class and then call a static method on it like `$segmentInstance->track(...)`. I thought that would be bad practice, because it "conceals" that I call `track(...)` in a static context?

Comment: I'm sorry for deleting my old comment, thought to catch up piece by piece. So for understanding here's the comment that should've been between the two of Quasdunk :) "Oh, but I have to say that I thought about using an additional wrapper class which maps exactly the same methods of the official Segment class to non-static ones. But because my wrapper described in the question is already especially for Segment that wouldn't be a clean solution."

Comment: Calling static methods in a non-static context is perfectly fine :) So there's no problem with something like `(new Segment)->track()` whatsoever, even if `track()` is static. It's the other way around that doesn't work: Calling non-static methods in a static context.

Comment: Alright, if that's the case thanks a lot! I'll leave this open so maybe someone comes up with a solution that works out of the box. Until then I'll use your approach :)

Comment: Sure, would like to to see a more interesting solution to this, too :) There is a thing called *[Prophecy](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.prophecy)* that PHPUnit has built in. It actually allows you to define assertions on a real class, run some code and then check if the assertions were met. I've never actually worked with it, but I think it should actually do the trick in your case. But, as pointed out, it's highly opinionated and therefore maybe not necessarily recommended.

Comment: Never mind, had a closer look at prophecies, that's not really what I had in mind. They just seem to have the same functionality as `Mockery::spy()`, but you still need to somehow inject the mock into your class under test. But I'm sure I have seen something along the lines of making assertions on something without injecting but, but I can't remember what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you cannot mock classes with static calls.

Static calls always reference exactly the class and method to be called, which is equivalent to pointing to exactly the file and line of code to be executed (if you assume basic autoloading capability is available).

The only way to execute different code is to NOT having included the original class, but to load the mock class code first. It does not matter if you have an alternative code file, or if you are calling `eval()` by using Mockery. Both ways will work.

But they will also work only one time. You cannot switch back to the original code in a later test, because the class can only be defined once per script run. And not being able to switch implementations (like original vs. mocked vs. another mocked) is the problem here.

The solution, which also was mentioned in the comments: Don't have classes with static methods. Always create instances of classes and call dynamic methods. This way you can easily mock the class, but it requires to create an instance first, and offer a way to inject the class (or at least the mocked class) into the code you want to test.

As a generic pattern I am using this if dependency injection is not available in the project (I have to deal with some legacy stuff at times):

```
public function __construct(MyClass $class = null) {
    $this->class = $class ?: new MyClass();
}
```

This way I don't have to inject the class, but I would be able to inject a mock instead of the real class.

For situations where dependency injection is available, the constructor will be a very basic initializer:

```
public function __construct(MyClass $class) {
    $this->class = $class;
}
```

This works great if your dependency injection framework is able to do auto wiring (like PHP-DI), and you only have exactly one `MyClass`, because this will be automatically injected without you having to define anything.

Comment: Thanks Sven! In my own code I use dependency injection wherever possible, but in this case I have to mock an official package (the Segment PHP Integration). This package is written in a completely static manner so I was looking for a way to mock this class - I can't change it.

Comment: Looking at the library, I don't like it in several details. However, you can deal with the situation in several ways. 1. You can ignore the static class that passes all calls into the instantiated objects internally, and do the same yourself. 2. You can wrap the static class with an instatiated wrapper that you can then mock.

Comment: Thank you, good to know that there's really no easier way to do this.